# iOS: Is it possible to delete cells in cellForRow data source

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, datasource

Is it possible to delete a cell in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

I've tried using the following method inside the UITableView datasource.

```
 [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

However, my app crashes when I try this. I get the assertion failure crash.

The reason why I am attempting this is because there is certain data that can show up while the user scrolls and I want to delete it as I go. However, I believe I might have to do it before hand.

Comment: Never do anything in `cellForRowAt` except return a cell.

Comment: Okay, I thought as much. Also, it's a good idea to set cell information in the cellForRow method right?

Comment: Yes, setting up the cell for the given indexPath is what you should do in that method.

Answer (score 0):

You app is crashing because you are just deleting the cell from the UI not the actual datasource.

**Option 1:**
1) First remove the item from that particular index from datasource
2) Reload table view

**Option 2:**
1) First remove the item from that particular index from datasource
2) Call the [self.tableview deleterowAtIndexpath:[Nsindexpath ... for the datasource item : withAnimation:UItableViewanimation.. function]]

Option 2 is jsut ot show some animation while removing.

*You can call these outside the cellforrow function liek any action button or function where you want to remove that item.*